# make_pair() in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I was doing the problem 337 from leetcode. This is the code I implemented.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    int rob(TreeNode* root) {

        unordered_map<TreeNode*, int> memo;

        return robSub(root, memo);
    }

private:
    int robSub(TreeNode* root, unordered_map<TreeNode*, int>& memo) {

        if (root == nullptr) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (memo.find(root) != memo.end()) {
            return memo.find(root)->second;
        }

        int leftGrand = 0;
        int rightGrand = 0;

        if (root->left != nullptr) {
            leftGrand = robSub(root->left->left, memo) + robSub(root->left->right, memo);
        }
        if (root->right != nullptr) {
            rightGrand = robSub(root->right->left, memo) + robSub(root->right->right, memo);
        }

        int result = max(root->val + leftGrand + rightGrand, robSub(root->left, memo) + robSub(root->right, memo));

        memo.insert(make_pair<TreeNode*, int>(root, result));
        return result;

    }
};
```

Then it reported an error:

```
Line 42: Char 59: error: no matching function for call to `make_pair<TreeNode*, int>(TreeNode*&, int&))`
```

Why the error happened and the arguments in `make_pair<>()` become references? Can someone help?

I modified `make_pair<TreeNode*, int>(root, result)` to `make_pair(root, result)`, then it worked. What's the differences between them?

Comment: Please don'y show us images of text, copy-paste the text itself instead.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You should accompany your question with a [mcve], where all unnecessary code is stripped. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Don't specify template arguments of `std::make_pair`. Let the compiler deduce them.

---

The meaning of template parameters of [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) was changed in C++11.

It used to be:

```
template <class T1, class T2> /*...*/ make_pair( T1 t, T2 u );
```

But now it is:

```
template <class T1, class T2> /*...*/ make_pair(T1 &&t, T2 &&u);
// `t` and `u` are forwarding references.
```

The code was valid pre-C++11, but it no longer is.

You could change the template arguments accordingly: `make_pair<TreeNode*&, int&>(root, result)`, but there is no reason to specify them manually. The compiler can deduce them just fine.

If you don't understand why the template arguments have to be references, read about *forwarding references*.

---

> Why ... the arguments in `make_pair<>()` become references?

Probably your compiler displayed argument types as references to indicate that you're passing lvalues into `make_pair`.

Answer (score -1):

When you have a

```
unordered_map<TreeNode*, int>& memo
```

and you want to insert an element:

```
memo.insert(make_pair<TreeNode*, int>(root, result));
```

There are several overloads that would match. My guess (but please think about this a bit) is that you want the one taking a `const value_type&` as argument. In that case, just construct the pair doing exactly that:

```
memo.insert(unordered_map<TreeNode*, int>::value_type(root, result));
```

The sole reason why you use `make_pair()` is to let the compiler pick the template parameters (less typing, a generic `pair<type1, type2>` ctor). If you want to specify the types explicitly, you can use the plain `pair` ctor. In this case though, I'd consider it an implementation detail of `unordered_map` and instead use its nested typedef. That typedef is btw. `std::pair<const Key, T>`!

All this leaves me with one question only: Why not use `memo[root] = result`?

Comment: The issue is `make_pair<TreeNode*, int>` becomes `make_pair(TreeNode*&&, int&&)`.  This wont wortk because `root` and `result` are lvalues.

Comment: That's clear, @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica, so I don't know why you're mentioning this!? In particular, I'm not suggesting that `make_pair()` should be used at all in this case!

Comment: You say *and you want to insert an element:
and you want to insert an element: memo.insert(make_pair<TreeNode\*, int>(root, result)); There are several overloads that would match. My guess (but please think about this a bit) is that you want the one taking a const value_type& as argument.* which is blaming `insert`, not `make_pair`

Comment: I'm just quoting the IMHO relevant parts of the original question and trying to interpret their intent.